# Prestashop 1.7 - Browser previous button not working on products page

Tags: pagination, navigation, prestashop-1.7

So I'm on my products page, when I go at the bottom of my page, underneath all my products and I clic on "2" to go to the next page it works.

I want to go back to the previous page, but if I use the previous button from my browser it don't work.

The URL change but the page doesn't refresh and stay on the page "2".

Someone know why ?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe the second page is loaded via Ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely by accident I solved the issue by adding a bit of JavaScript in my pagination.tpl file.

Here the code :

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
   location.reload();
});
```

If I understand right, it refresh the page when there a URL change.

Hope it will help some people !